# Whats wrong with this c++ reverse string function

Tags: c++, string

```
void reverse (char s[]){
int len = strlen(s);
int j = len - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++,j--){
    cout << s[i];
    char ch = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j]; //error line - giving exception, cannot write to the memory
    s[j] = ch;
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studion 2008 and i can't understand whats the problem here .. :s .. I am out of C++ practice :$ .

Comment: Are you passing `reverse()` a compile-time constant string perchance?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: If you really, really like to use char arrays as strings use something like char c[] = "something"; instead of char *c = "something";

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that it uses C-style strings instead of C++ style strings. In particular, you are apparently trying to write to a constant *string literal*:

```
char const* str = "I cannot be written to";
```

C++ allows to omit the `const` here for backwards compatibility but **the literal is still constant**.

Finally, C++ already has a `reverse` function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This. std::string and std::reverse are the way to go.

Comment: Actually, as someone pointed out to me a while back, C++03 officially deprecates using char* to point at literals.  See Annex D.4

Comment: i don't want to use built in reverse methods. have to write own string reverse for some pof thing.

Comment: @alee: you can, of course. The basic logic of your code is correct, and it will still work with C++ strings. The important bit of my answer is the first part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the problem is with how you're calling it, probably with a string literal, something like:

```
reverse("This is a string");
```

or:
    char *string = "This is a string";
    reverse(string);

or some other minor variation. In any case, you're trying to write to a string literal, which gives undefined behavior.

Since you're apparently using C++, I'd consider using an `std::string` instead:

```
void reverse(std::string &s) { 
    int j=s.length()-1;
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++, j--) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this on a `const char*` or a string literal?

Are you trying to reverse

```
reverse("foo");
```

or

```
char *s = "foo";
reverse(s);
```

You'll need to create a new string from the non-writeable one and reverse *that* instead.  You can use `strdup`.

```
char *s = strdup("foo");
reverse(s);
free(s, strlen(s));
```

Also note that your question is tagged c++, so you should probably be using `std::string`.